# PHP Find and replace function

Tags: php, regex, replace

I need a regular expression find and replace that I'm a little stuck on.

Basically, I have a table with several `<td>`'s
in each `<td>` i have a`<img>`

I need to copy the width and height from the `<img>` and place it in the `<td>`

I have been doing this manually, however the number of `<td>`'s is growing and its taking to long.

I just need help doing the actual find and replace

any ideas?

-- EDIT --

Thanks for the advice, Think I will go down the dom route as I know it better.
I have done reg ex before which did a task which was a much more simple idea so just went from there. You've saved me some time

Comment: do u make string concatenation any where?

Comment: this would likely be easier and more robust if you used the DOMDocument class rather than trying string manipulation.

Comment: Don't use a regular expression for html parsing... php has a couple nice xml parsers, I'm personally a fan of http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: How are you building this table? If it's via script, then have the script do the extraction/filling-in. Otherwise, use DOM to parse/process the html. Anything you can do with substring matching/regexes will be unreliable.

Comment: Why do you always people want to use regex? There are usually simpler and easier ways to reach your target!

Comment: @Sam Dufel simplexml only works on valid xml, where as DOMDocument will load html pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using the [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class provided by PHP.

**Example:**

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTMLFile('/path/to/file.html');

// Find the TD elements.
$tds = $doc->getElementsByTagName('td');

// If TD elements were found, loop through each one of them.
if ( ! empty($tds) )
  foreach ( $tds as $td )
  {
    // Find the IMG elements located inside that TD
    $imgs = $td->getElementsByTagName('img');

    // Find the style attribute of the TD just in case one already exists.
    $style = $td->getAttribute('style');
    
    // I'm not sure what to do if multiple images are found so instead of looping to many, make sure only 1 is found.
    if ( ! empty($imgs) && count($imgs) == 1 )
    {
      $height = $imgs->item(0)->getAttribute('height');
      $width = $imgs->item(0)->getAttribute('width');

      if ( ! empty($height) )
        $style .= 'height:' . $height . 'px;';

      if ( ! empty($width) )
        $style .= 'width:' . $width . 'px;';
      
      // Update the style attribute of the TD element.
      $td->setAttribute('style', $style);
    }
  }

// Save the HTML document.
$doc->saveHTMLFile('/path/to/newfile.html');
```

**Updates:**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="test.png" height="100" width="100" /></td>
        <td>
          <p><img src="test2.png" height="100" /></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

**To:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td style="height:100px;width:100px;"><img src="test.png" height="100" width="100"></td>
        <td style="height:100px;">
          <p><img src="test2.png" height="100"></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your help, saved me a lot of head aches

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without Regular Expressions. Try something like this:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i=0, j=images.length; i<j; i++){
    images[i].parentNode.setAttribute('height', images[i].height);
    images[i].parentNode.setAttribute('width', images[i].width);
}
```

The script assumes that you have no images other than you mentioned above.

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:php] not [tag:javascript].

Comment: im getting "document.getElementsTagName is not a function" error on this one.

Comment: @DAVIEAC - It should be `document.getElementsByTagName` (it's missing the By).

Comment: I was looking for questions tagged regex when I got to this question and din't see the PHP tag. Sorry, for the tangle

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
preg_replace('/<td>(.*?)<img(.*?)width=\"(\d+)(.*?)height=\"(\d+)(.*?)<\/td>/','<td width="${3}" height="${5}">${1}<img${2}width="${3}${4}height="${5}${6}</td>', $html);
```

switch width and height if necessary =)